# Query to take partial backup in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

```
 I tried to take full backup in mysql using enterprise backup by using the command

    mysqlbackup -u root -p --backup-dir=g:\full_bck backup
```

But I could not take backup of a single database , I tried it using --include database_name.

Please help me to sort out this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The syntax for taking MySQL dump:**

```
-- Dump all databases and all tables (option "-A" is similar to "--all-databases")
mysqldump -u [username] -p[user_password] -A > [dump_filename]
-- Example, please note (NO SPACE between -p and your password)
mysqldump -u root -pmypass -A > full_dumb.sql

-- Dump single database
mysqldump -u [username] -p[user_password] [database_name] > [dump_filename]
-- Example
mysqldump -u root -pmypass dbshopping > dbshopping_dumb.sql
```

**UPDATE:**

```
-- MySQL Enterprise Backup Syntax
mysqlbackup --user[username] --password=[user_password] --backup-dir=[backup_directory] --databases=[database_list] backup

-- Example Command
mysqlbackup --user=root --password=mypass --backup-dir=G:\mysql-enterprise-backup-directory --databases=dbshopping backup
```

I'm not an expert in 'MySQL Enterprise Backup', yet *It worked fine for me...*

> You can also verify backup history and/or progress from 'mysql'
>   database

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.backup_progress;
SELECT * FROM mysql.backup_history;
```

Hope this may help you...